# Filter out specific Goal using analytics API in Excel

Tags: api, analytics

For one of my analytics properties I wish to filter out one specific goals. At the moment I'm using `ga:goalCompletionsAll` to get the goals. The goal I was to filter out is `Goal 10`. Is this even possible or is there a workaround without getting all the other `goals` apart from each other?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I though of a work around myself, I added the metric for goal 10 and made the formula like this 'AllGoals - Goal10'.